# Date picker sencha touch 2

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a date picker field dynamically. I need to set the picker field value to a textfield. somehow i am unable to retrieve the picker value. The date picker is displayed but the done button is throwing an error saying "Cannot call method "Todatestring" of undefined.

My code is :

```
 case 'date':
                    var cmp1 = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                        text:'Date:',
                        ui:'plain',
                        id:'datepicker',
                        handler:function () {

                            var datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.picker.Date', {
                                dateFormat:'Y-m-d',
                                id:'picker1',
                                doneButton:{
                                    listeners:{
                                        // when the done button is tapped, set the value
                                        tap:function (button, event, eOpts) {
                                            console.log('inside done button');
                                            console.log(Ext.getCmp('picker1').getValue());
                                           /* var picker = this.up('datepicker');
                                            picker.fireEvent('change', picker, picker.getValue());*/
                                            console.log('done button');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            Ext.getCmp('overlayId').add(datePicker);
                            datePicker.show();
                            Ext.getCmp('datefield').setValue('');

                        }
                    });
                    Ext.getCmp('overlayId').add({ xtype:'container', padding:10, items:[cmp1] });
                    var cmp = Ext.create('Ext.field.Text', {
                        //label:'Date:',
                        id:'datefield',
                        listener:{
                            focus:function () {
                                console.log('on blue function called');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to override the setValue() function direct. Better approach is to override the applyValue() or/and updateValue() functions. 
See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system for more information about config properties and how apply/update/set pattern does work

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: hi, i have modified the code based on the done button provided by the datepicker. It enters the function as the console is being printed but i am unable to retrive the value. Any idea how do i get that?

Comment: i tried using applyValue/updateValue, but it never entered the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

i know its late, but help somebody later, you can use change listener to get selected date value dynamically

```
 datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.picker.Date', {
               itemId:'ctsdateselect',

                    value: new Date(),
                    yearFrom: 1985,
                    yearTo  : 2050,

                listeners: {
                    change: function (value, eOpts) {

console.log(eOpts);

                    }, 
                    cancel: function (picker) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('You hit cancel', '');
                    } 
                } 

            });
datepicker.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it got fixed by setting value config for the datepicker.
To get the new value you actually need to have some initial value. [Check this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228713-Form.reset%28%29-and-datepicker-issue).